# Delete place picker value

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I have a flutterflow project with two `place picker`, i need to delete it's values on a action, the `onload` of a page.
So the problem is that i dont see any configuration that allows me to do that.

I've tried with update app state configuration and nothing appears.
I've tried with Widgets/Ui configuration and nothing appears.

I dont know how to delete the place picker value, I would like to get some step by step guide of how to delete place picker data.